# Auto generator of PropTypes.shape from an object (similar to createGraphqlQuery)

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I need to define the structure of data for two reasons. One for PropTypes, and another for GraphQL query. So I create an object like this:

```
const SHAPE = {
    id: 'string.isRequired',
    name: 'string.isRequired',
    address: 'string.isRequired',
    creator: {
        displayname: 'string.isRequired',
        id: 'string.isRequired'
    }
}
```

I wrote a function to create a graphql query from this, but then I found graphql generators for me! I tried to do the same for React PropTypes, does anyone know of one?

It should convert the above to:

```
PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    address: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    creator: PropTypes.shape({
        displayname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
})
```

I just thought I might ask before I crash for the night. I wasted time doing the graphql one >_< haha

Answer (score 2):

This is also a nice tool to generate your PropTypes:

https://github.com/rmosolgo/prop-types

- you can try it online

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote this little something for myself, it works, it might help others:

Dependencies:

```
function isObject(avar) {
    // cosntructor.name tested for `function Animal(){}; var a = new Animal(); isObject(a);` will return true otherwise as it is [Object object]
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(avar) === '[object Object]' && avar.constructor.name === 'Object';
}

function deepAccessUsingString(obj, dotpath) {
  dotpath.split('.').reduce((nested, key) => nested[key], obj);
}
```

And here is the code:

```
import { PropTypes } from 'react';

function createPropTypeShape(obj) {
    let shape = {};
    let isrequired = obj.isRequired;
    delete obj.isRequired;
    let isarray = obj.isArray;
    delete obj.isArray;

    for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj))
        shape[key] = isObject(val) ? createPropTypeShape(val) : deepAccessUsingString(PropTypes, val);

    let rshape = PropTypes.shape(shape);
    if (isarray) rshape = PropTypes.arrayOf(rshape);
    return isrequired ? rshape.isRequired : rshape;
}
```

I added a feature, for a key to be `isRequired` bool, and `isArray` bool this tells me if the shape is required: using it on the OP:

```
const SHAPE = {
    isRequired: true,
    id: 'string.isRequired',
    name: 'string.isRequired',
    address: 'string.isRequired',
    creator: {
        isRequired: false, // can omit falsey value
        displayname: 'string.isRequired',
        id: 'string.isRequired'
    },
    comments {
        isArray: true,
        isRequired: true,
        text: 'string.isRequired'
    }
}
```

`createPropTypesShape(SHAPE)` gives:

```
PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    address: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    creator: PropTypes.shape({
        displayname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }) // notice that this is NOT required
    comments: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({ // notice that this is arrayOf due to `isArray: true`
        text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }))
}).isRequired
```

#### GraphQL part

If you're interested in the grpahql query generator, here is that:

```
export function createGqlQuery(obj) {
    let shape = [];

    delete obj.isRequired;
    delete obj.isArray;

    for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj))
      shape.push(isObject(val) ? `${key} ${createGqlQuery(val)}` : key);

    return '{' + shape.join(' ') + '}';
}
```

running this on the shape above gives:

`createGqlQuery(SHAPE)` -> `{id name address creator {displayname id} comments {text}}`